# Python - Minimum of a List of Instance Variables

Tags: python, list, min

I'm new to Python and I really love the `min` function.

```
>>>min([1,3,15])
0
```

But what if I have a list of instances, and they all have a variable named `number`?

```
class Instance():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

i1 = Instance(1)
i2 = Instance(3)
i3 = Instance(15)
iList = [i1,i2,i3]
```

Do I really have to something like

```
lowestI = iList[0].number
for i in iList:
    if lowestI > iList[i].number: lowestI = iList[i].number
print lowestI
```

Can't I use `min` in a nice pythonic way?

Comment: Your `min` function must be broken... `min([1,3,15])` gives me `1` ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The OOP way would be to implement `__lt__`:

```
class Instance():
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.number < other.number
        # now min(iList) just works
```

Another way is

`imin = min(iList, key=lambda x:x.number)`

Functions like `sort, min, max` all take a `key` argument. You give a function that takes an item and returns whatever should stand for this item when comparing it.

Answer (score 10):

```
from operator import attrgetter
min( iList, key = attrgetter( "number" ) )
```

The same `key` argument also works with `sort`, for implementing the decorate-sort-undecorate idiom Pythonically.

Comment: `min( iList, key = attrgetter( "number" ) )`

Comment: attrgetter and itemgetter rock - a lot of lambda functions can be eliminated by using them.  They are faster than lambda and IMHO easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

Generator syntax:

```
min(i.number for i in iList)
```

`key` function:

```
min(iList, key=lambda i: i.number)
```

Comment: `key` is better than generator as it keeps the reference to the instance.

Answer (score 1):

```
min(iList, key=lambda inst: inst.number)
```